# Group elements by attribute in new XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Good afternoon!

Having this xml snippet:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="trasnf.xsl"?>
<Shapes xmlns="namespaceProject"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="namespaceProject validator.xsd">
    <Shape id="id1">
            <Type>Square</Type>
            <Data>
                <Color>Red</Color>
            </Data>
        </Shape>
    <Shape id="id2">
            <Type>Circle</Type>
            <Data>
                <Color>Blue</Color>
            </Data>
        </Shape>
    <Shape id="id3">
            <Type>Triangle</Type>
            <Data>
                <Color>Red</Color>
            </Data>
        </Shape>
<Shapes>
```

And wanting the XML output be like:

```
<Shapes>
    <Color name="Red">
            <Type>Square</Type>
            <Type>Triangle</Type>
    </Color>
    <Color name="Blue">
            <Type>Circle</Type>
    </Color>
<Shapes>
```

How can I do that in XSLT?
This is what I've tried from what I read on the internet and in other user's questions, but it still doesn't print correctly. It just ouput text, and not tags, by dragging the xml to the browser (tried Internet Explorer and Firefox).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0" xmlns:p="namespaceProject">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<Shapes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/p:Shapes/p:Shape/p:Data/p:Color[not(. = ../../preceding-sibling::p:Data/p:Color)]"/>
</Shapes>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p:Color">
    <xsl:element name="Color">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="/p:Shapes/p:Shape[p:Data/p:Color = current()]">
            <xsl:element name="Type">
                <xsl:value-of select="p:Type"/>
            </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete snippets to allow us to reproduce the problem, I don't see any namespaces used in the input snippet so the use of a prefix in the XSLT snippet seems unnecessary. And you haven't even shown how you declare the namespace. As for "It just ouput text", how do you run the XSLT transformation?

Comment: I've added the missing parts related to the namespace. Thanks!

Comment: "*This is what I've tried from what I read on the internet and in other user's questions,*" You've been reading the wrong sources. Read this instead: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can correct the apply-templates to `<xsl:apply-templates select="/p:Shapes/p:Shape/p:Data/p:Color[not(. = ../../preceding-sibling::p:Shape/p:Data/p:Color)]"/>` to fix your code. Note however that grouping is done easier and more efficiently with `xsl:for-each-group` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples) in XSLT 2.0 or with [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) in XSLT 1.0. And result elements for which you do not need to compute the name can be created simply as literals, as in `<Type>...</Type>` instead of `<xsl:element name="Type">...</xsl:element>`.